# UIKeyboard key sizes

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

Does anyone know the size of a key or how to find the sizes of keys in the on screen keyboard for iPhone and iPad? I'm making a few custom keyboards for my app and I want them to look very much like the original keyboard. Or if you know of a way to just change the keys on the existing keyboard that would also work.
Thanks in advance, Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What’s wrong with taking screen shots?

Comment: No, the way to find the size is to take a screen shot (and then measure in Photoshop).

Comment: oh, ok that makes sense thank you. LOL i guess it was a stupid question

Comment: David, can you expand on this answer (just a tiny bit) to stop the flow of 'not an answer' flags?

Comment: The original question was "how big are keys." It

Comment: 1. Take a screen shot with the keyboard up. 2. Open the screen shot in Photoshop. 3. Select a key. 4. Look at the size of the selection.

Comment: I would maybe even use the individual keys taken from photoshop and use those as images for the UIButton and that would solve all of my problems, Thank you very much